# Bootstrap-4 disables clicking

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have the following [code](https://codepen.io/GuilleCol/pen/NWNWEKp?editors=1000) I did with bootstrap 4 and use a modal to create the following form, but clicking outside it disables. I need that when it's active, I can click on the elements outside.

I need to move around the map without disabling the modal.

when using

data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="false"

I can't move in the background

```css
 .modal.right.fade.show .modal-dialog {
        left: 0;
    }
    
    .modal.left .modal-dialog {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        margin: auto;
        width: 400px;
        height: 100%;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
        -o-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
    }
    
    .modal-backdrop {
        opacity: 0.0 !important;
    }
    
    .padding {
        padding-top: 15px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
    }
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-VCmXjywReHh4PwowAiWNagnWcLhlEJLA5buUprzK8rxFgeH0kww/aWY76TfkUoSX" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.0.0/animate.min.css" />
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" style="position: fixed; right: 0;">Modal</button>

    <iframe style="width: 100%; height: 700px;" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d15906.095346250848!2d-74.1592274!3d4.6786168!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1ses!2sco!4v1596647912474!5m2!1ses!2sco" frameborder="0"
        style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0"></iframe>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal left fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                        <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                        <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                        <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" aria-selected="false">Cerrar</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                        <div class="padding">
                            <h4>Busqueda por Texto</h4>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresa una palabra clave a buscar, codigo postal, ciudad">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
                        <div class="padding">
                            <h4>Búsqueda Avanzada</h4>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <label>Departamento / Municipio:</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Departamento">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-row mt-1 mb-1">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Municipio">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <h6>Vía Principal</h6>
                            <div class="form-row mt-1">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Típo de Via">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Número">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-2">
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1">
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">Bis</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-row mt-1 mb-1">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Letra">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Cuadrante">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <h6>Vía Generadora</h6>
                            <div class="form-row mt-1">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Número">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Letra">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Número">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Cuadrante">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row mt-2">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Guardar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">...</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-XEerZL0cuoUbHE4nZReLT7nx9gQrQreJekYhJD9WNWhH8nEW+0c5qq7aIo2Wl30J" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using *data-backdrop="static"* in your modal.